# Нахождение имени пользователя при подключении к Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ldap

Необходимо узнавать имя пользователя запускающего программу и работающего с базой данных для занесения информации о нем в базу при добавлении данных. Узнаю его имя через команду Environment.UserName. Но если человек работает с личного компьютера подключенного к сети через VPN доступ к базе он имеет как доменный пользователь, но Environment.UserName показывает его имя на личном компьютере. Может кто знает как узнать доменное имя по которому он подключен к базе?

Comment: Тег EF здесь абсолютно лишний. Вы узнаёте каким-то образом имя и потом подставляете его в строку подключения, верно? С тем же успехом можно просто вывести в консоль: никаких специфичных особенностей EF не будет уже вообще.

Comment: @AK может кто знает как его при подключении к entity вытаскивать?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, **никогда не верьте клиенту!** Забудьте, что вы в принципе можете на клиенте как-то узнать имя пользователя и передать его в БД. Вам не следовало даже думать, что `Environment.UserName` может означать что-то полезное в плане базы данных.

Если пользователь может подключиться к БД под доменной "учёткой" - значит, вы скорее всего используете MS SQL Server и вы можете использовать CURRENT_USER в качестве его имени:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Дальше, нужно этот CURRENT_USER как-то вставить в запрос. Самый простой (но совершенно небезопасный!) способ - это добавить его значением по умолчанию:

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CreatedBy DEFAULT CURRENT_USER FOR [createdBy]
```

В таком случае эту колонку в EF вам придётся пометить как вычислимую (Computed), чтобы она не затиралась при вставке. **Но это абсолютно небезопасное решение!**

---

Правильный способ обеспечения безопасности в двухзвенной архитектуре - хранимые процедуры и триггеры.

В варианте с хранимыми процедурами вы полностью запрещаете пользователям менять содержимое таблиц напрямую, и вместо этого пишете хранимую процедуру на каждую операцию.

Вариант с триггерами чуть попроще, тут вы просто навешиваете триггер на таблицу:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER fooInserted ON foo FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE foo
    SET createdBy = CURRENT_USER, modifiedBy = CURRENT_USER
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)

END

CREATE TRIGGER fooUpdated ON foo FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE foo
    SET modifiedBy = CURRENT_USER
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)

END
```

Comment: Что-то у меня как ни крути, `SELECT CURRENT_USER` выдает "dbo" (видимо, это схема пользователя в текущей базе). Как сделать, чтобы было настоящее имя пользователя?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight попробуйте зайти под пользователем без роли sysadmin

Comment: Без sysadmin вывелось "guest". Теперь стало понятно, в чем дело, понятия "пользователь" и "имя входа" то не равнозначны. Сопоставления имени входа пользователю в БД не было, поэтому и выводилось стандартное dbo. Тут видимо `SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` больше подходит, когда нужно всегда вывести имя входа.